# Cannot import a function from a file.py

Tags: importerror, pylance, ipynb

I'm trying to run a script.ipynb, but when import a function from a file.py I have this error.

[image: Error]

I tried to change interpreter in visual studio code, but it still doesn't work. Then I installed pylance, but nothing.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `from 2903`? `2903` is an integer literal.

Comment: 2903 is the name of the file.py where there are the functions. I tryed to write from 2903.py but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to rename the file?

Comment: I tried everything except renaming the file! Thanks, it worked